# GWT Designer for eclipse not working

Tags: google-plugin-eclipse, gwt-designer

I have recently installed Eclipse Luna and the gwt-eclipse plugin.
I have created Project with the default GWT Aplication generated by the wizard, which I have called "pru".

I can compile and run the Project correctly.
But if I try to use the Design View to modify the interface controls, opening the Pru.java file (with Open With/GWT Designer) I get an error.
It tries to parse the file and then throws an error:

```
Internal Error
 encountered unexpected internal error. 

 This could be caused by a bug or by a misconfiguration issue, conflict, partial update, etc.

 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/TreeLogger;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lcom/google/gwt/dev/cfg/ModuleDef;
```

I am running in a Surface Pro 3 with Windows 8.1 x64 
I have installed Eclipse Luna under c:\Program Files

I have installed Apache Ant 1.9.4 and Java JDK SE 1.8.0_25-b18 64 bits version (I have tried with 32 bit version too, and with jdk 1.7)

I have configuered the PATH, ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME variables to point to the correct installed directories.

I have used the "install new software" option in eclipse to install the gwt plugins.

I have installed following packages from https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4:

Google Plugin for Eclipse
GWT Designer for GPE
SDKS (GWT SDK 2.6.0 and Google App Engine Java SDK 1.9.17)

Do you have any idea of what's going on?

Thank you for your help.